# Constructive expectancy in a hotel

Tags: combinatorics

There are $20$ rooms at a hotel. $9$ rooms are occupied by $2$ people each, $7$ rooms are each occupied by a single person, and $4$ rooms are vacant.

If you talk to a random guest of the hotel, then, assuming that person is equally likely to be any of the guests at the hotel, what is the expected number of people staying in that person's room including themselves?

The expectancy of how many occupants there are in a random room is $\frac{5}{4}$

The expectancy of how many occupants there are in any occupied room is $\frac{25}{6}.$

There is a pattern here, but I just can't seem to get the expectancy of a single person.

Comment: Can you express the probability of the following events? (i) You talk to a person chosen uniformly at random; that person turns out to be person 7 (out of the 25 in the hotel). (ii) You talk to a random (again uniformly) person, and that person happens to be in a room occupied by exactly two people?

Comment: How many people are staying in doubles rooms?  How many are staying in singles rooms?  What is the probability that a randomly selected person is in a doubles room?

Comment: Thank you for the hints! I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it not $2 \left(\frac{18}{25}\right) + 1\left(\frac{7}{25}\right)=\frac{43}{25}$?